# How to send DateTime to .net webService from android (ksoap2)?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I've a .net webservice, where I have to send a param (type of dateTime), as You can see:

```
 <startDateTime>dateTime</startDateTime>
```

In Android client, I use ksoap2, and I don't know , How to send that type of data?
Please help with **setting this type** - code below not works.

```
PropertyInfo propInfo3 = new PropertyInfo();
propInfo3.name="startDateTime";
propInfo3.value="2012-02-01";
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I call web service methods in my application. Note the method I used to convert java dates. You require an ISO date format.

```
protected static Object callMethod(String method, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, method);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.headerOut = new Element[1];
    envelope.headerOut[0] = buildAuthHeader();
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    if (parameters != null) {
        for (String item : parameters.keySet()) {
            Object itemValue = parameters.get(item);
            if (itemValue.getClass().getName().equals("java.util.Date")) {
                // If it's a date then we have to format it because ksoap
                // does not know how to do this.
                request.addProperty(item, getSOAPDateString((java.util.Date) itemValue));
            } else {
                request.addProperty(item, itemValue);
            }
        }
    }

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS, 10000);
    httpTransport.debug = true;

    httpTransport.call(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE + "/" + method, envelope);
    String soapString = httpTransport.requestDump;
    System.out.println(soapString);
    return envelope.getResponse();
}
```

Here is the method that returns the actual string:

```
private static Object getSOAPDateString(java.util.Date itemValue) {
    String lFormatTemplate = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'";
    DateFormat lDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(lFormatTemplate);
    String lDate = lDateFormat.format(itemValue);

    return lDate;
}
```

Comment: Does this solution work for you? I get the 

"SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@405944b8"

Also your format will produce a "Z" at the end? I believe you should be using "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Comment: I've since switched to JSON services, but this worked perfectly for me over the course of a few months. My .net service accepted dates in that format. Have you debugged the service call on your .Net service yet? Object reference.. is definitely a .Net error.

Comment: I was doing something immensely stupid (calling a similar looking method that did NOT take a dateTime). On my quest to solve this and before I realized I learnt how to use the MarshalDate class provided and am now using that.

Answer (score 0):

In your server, what's the return from the client?

When I have a problem like this, I show in the Logcat on Android what I'm sending and in the server side what I'm getting.

I had a little problem with date too (I'm using ksoap2 and webservices), I solve my problem sending the date in the util.Date, then I use SimpleDateFormat with a pattern date in my project and convert that string to what I want.

cya,
Bertan

---

Here is my code that sends to the WS:

```
public static byte[] send(String... param) throws SocketTimeoutException, IOException, XmlPullParserException, Exception{
            //First I send the WS Name
    String ws = param[0];
            //Second is the operationName
    SoapObject soap = new SoapObject(URL_SOAP, param[1]);

    Object retorno = null;

    int tamParam = param.length;

            //The 3 parameter for the infinity its the properties, name and the next it's the value...
    if (tamParam > 0) {
        for (int i = 2; i < tamParam; i++) {
            soap.addProperty(param[i], param[++i]);
        }
    }

    // create a envelope for the soap object
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap);

    // create a HttpTransport to send the object soap with 15s delay
    MyHttpTransport httpTransport = new MyHttpTransport(URL + ws, 15000);

    // send the req
    Long tempo1 = 0l;
        tempo1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        httpTransport.call("", envelope);

        retorno = envelope.getResponse();
        Long tempo2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    httpTransport.reset();
    //I ever get byte[] from the WS...
    if (retorno != null) {
        byte[] bloc = Base64.decode(retorno.toString(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        return bloc;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you paste your code - How you pass values to ProperyInfo Object?   Ive response from ws, but data is empty (no results), but i have Soap message - so I assume, that parameters not properly set up :(

Comment: thanks, but...  Is your ws id .NET ? i dont see "envelope.dotNet=true"... second, You use: soap.addProperty(param[i], param[++i]);
, so its similar to this: propInfo3.name="startDateTime";  WHAT ABOUT SETTING type?
propInfo3.value="2012-02-01";

Comment: no, my ws isn't a .Net.

the soap.addProperty(param[i], param[++i]); is like a hashMap, its like soap.addProperty(key, value);

so in your project u need do like soap.addProperty("startDateTime","2012-02-01");

I'm not using PropertyInfo detached the envelope, I'm putting the values direct in the Soap object, my soap variable are declared: SoapObject soap = new SoapObject(URL_SOAP, WEB_SERVICE_NAME);

Comment: do u hear about marshaling date? I'm testing it right now... i've use code -like yours - but got error - cannot serialize :(

Comment: heh, your magic code works :) soap.addProperty(key, value); setting as string...  strange :)